# Why IF statement and strcmp always return FALSE - PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Here I have assign the string like "India" to `$country` variable using `document.write()` function.
It's also print the string "India". But it return `-1` when I am trying to `strcmp` and return "False" while in IF statement.

```
  <script language="Javascript"> 
    var country_var = geoplugin_countryName();  //India
  </script>

<?php
echo $country = "<script>document.write(country_var);</script>"; //Return : India

echo strcmp($country,"India"); //Return : -1

if(trim($country) == 'India')
    echo "<br>True";   
else   
    echo "<br>False";      
?>
```

I know that PHP is Server Side and JS is Client Side language.

Is it possible to compare any other ways?
Thanks!

Comment: `"<script>document.write('India');</script>"` is a `string` and it is not equal to `"India"`

Comment: But it return "India" when i am echo.

Comment: You are `echoing` script which is being executed by browser... `document.write` writes a string of text to a document stream

Comment: the PHP is executed **on the server**, the javascript on the client browser. Youre confused with server side languages.

Comment: @RamaLingam, javascript code is not executed on PHP. Javascript is a client side language. Whatever code is there in JS, it is just a string for PHP.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to compare that or not?

Comment: `strpos` It's working fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing string `"India"` to a string `"<script>document.write('India');</script>"`. You can see visually that these 2 strings are nowhere equal or identical.

One way to return true would be to check whether that long-script-string containts string "India", not saying that's the best way to achieve what you are doing with it, moreover it's probably a wrong way but still a way:

```
if (strpos($country, 'India') !== false) {
    echo 'The country string has India in it';
}
```

Another way would be to remove `"<script>document.write('"` and `"');</script>"` from variable $country and only then to compare them.
You can do that with `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()`.

In any case you should compare a clean variable with a string first and only then wrap that variable in `<script>` tag, so:

```
<?php
    echo $country = "India"; //Return : India

    echo strcmp($country, "India");

    if($country === "India")
        echo "<br>True";   
    else   
        echo "<br>False";      

    $country = "<script>document.write('" . $country . "');</script>";
?>
```

P.S. Although I don't understand why you even need to put the country name in `document.write()`?

Comment: PHP is being executed before JavaScript.
So if you need a way to pass a variable from JavaScript to PHP you either need to send an AJAX query to a php script, or put the value using JavaScript into an html form and submit the form - that will make the page reload and then PHP will be able to access the data from $_POST array.

Comment: It's very useful way. Thanks!